# Unable to understand libusb API

Tags: c++, libusb, libusb-1.0

I am working in libusb and have minimal knowledge on C++. I am trying to understand the [API of libusb](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/libusb_api.html) and write code accordingly. But I am unable to understand how to declare and use variables as variable or pointer or double or triple pointer.

1. The below code is from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283618/libusb-how-to-get-vid-and-pid). How to find what level of pointers to be used while declaring these variables from the API documentation. Is there any documentation or tutorial videos that explains these things.

   ```
   libusb_context       *context    = NULL   ;
   libusb_device_handle *dev_handle = NULL   ;
   libusb_device        **devs               ;
   int                  rc          = 0      ;
   ssize_t              count                ; //holding number of devices in list
   ```

For example, consider [libusb_device_handle](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/group__libusb__dev.html#ga7df95821d20d27b5597f1d783749d6a4). How to declare this and use it?

```
typedef struct libusb_device_handle libusb_device_handle
```

2. The syntax of [libusb_strerror()](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/group__libusb__misc.html#ga554ec46d5fbaa29e26a85036a3621e53) is `const char * libusb_strerror (int errcode)`. The function returns constant string. Should I declare a char or char array or string to read the returned value. If the below way of usage right?

   ```
    char char *err_code;//declaration
    err_code = libusb_strerror(rc);
   ```

if the returned value is a string, then how can a characer pointer hold it?

An example would be really helpful.

3)Here is my entire code. I can open the device. But the bulk transfer command returns 5 and  fails. I am not sure at which part I am making mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libusb.h"

#define IN_EP  0x81
#define OUT_EP 0x02

int main(){
    libusb_context *context = NULL;
    libusb_device_handle *dev_handle = NULL ;
    libusb_device **devs ;
    int rc = 100 ;
    //ssize_t count ; //holding number of devices in list
    unsigned int vid=0x1234;
    unsigned int pid=0x5678;
    unsigned char data[10];
    data[0]=128;
    int transferred = 0;
    unsigned int timeout = 5000;
    //std::string str[100];
    const char* err_code;
    

    rc = libusb_set_option(context, LIBUSB_OPTION_LOG_LEVEL,2);
    if (rc==0){    std::cout<<"libusb_setOption worked:"<<rc<<"\n"; }
    else{   std::cout<<"libusb_setOption_Failed:"<<rc<<"\n";    }


    rc = libusb_init(&context);
    if (rc==0){    std::cout<<"libusb_init worked:"<<rc<<"\n"; }
    else{   std::cout<<"libusb_init Failed"<<rc<<"\n";    }


    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(context,vid,pid);
    if (dev_handle == NULL){
        std::cout<<"libusb_open Failed"<<"\n";
        libusb_exit(context);std::cout<<"libusb_exit"<<"\n";exit(1);    }
    else{    std::cout<<"libusb_opened"<<"\n";    }

    
    rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle,OUT_EP,data,1,&transferred, timeout);  //Send data to device
    if (rc==0){        std::cout<<"libusb_write worked:"<<rc<<"; Wrote "<<transferred<<" bytes\n";    }
    else{        std::cout<<"libusb__Write failed"<<rc<<"; Wrote "<<transferred<<" bytes\n";    }
    err_code = libusb_strerror(rc);
    
    rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle,IN_EP,data,3,&transferred, timeout);   //Read data from device
    if (rc==0){        std::cout<<"libusb_read worked:"<<rc<<" ; Read"<<transferred<<" bytes; Data:"<<data<<"\n";
    std::cout<<data[0]<<" "<<data[1]<<" "<<data[2]<<"\n";  }
    else{        std::cout<<"libusb__read failed"<<rc<<"; Read "<<transferred<<" bytes\n";    }

    
    libusb_close(dev_handle);
    std::cout<<"libusb_close"<<"\n";
    
    
    libusb_exit(context);
    std::cout<<"libusb_close"<<"\n";
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. [...] For example, consider `libusb_device_handle`. How to declare this and use it?

You declare it exactly like in your code:

```
libusb_device_handle *dev_handle = NULL;
```

Because `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid()` returns a *pointer* to `libusb_device_handle`, your `dev_handle` must also be a pointer to that.

You might be confused because of `devs` being a pointer-to-pointer. This is because it is actually returning a pointer to an array, but since you are not even using that in your code, I would forget about it for now.

> 2. The syntax of `libusb_strerror()` is `const char * libusb_strerror (int errcode)`. The function returns constant string. Should I declare a char or char array or string to read the returned value?

You should declare a variable exactly the same as the return type of `libusb_strerror()`, thus:

```
const char *err_string;
err_string = libusb_strerror(rc);
```

> If the returned value is a string, then how can a characer pointer hold it?

The returned value is a pointer, you just make a copy of the pointer. The pointer points to some part of memory where the string is stored. You don't have to worry about how libusb allocated it.

> 3. I can open the device. But the bulk transfer command returns 5 and fails. I am not sure at which part I am making mistake.

The code looks mostly fine, except you want to call `libusb_strerror()` *after* the second call to `libusb_bulk_transfer()`, not right before it. Error code -5 is `LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND`. This might mean it didn't find the endpoint. Are you sure `IN_EP` and `OUT_EP` are set correctly?